# Parsing xml file with matlab on linux with -nojvm option

Tags: linux, matlab, parsexml

I am trying parse an xml file using `parseXML` matlab function on linux with a `-nojvm` option. The `xmlread` function within `parseXML` does not read the xml file with the `-nojvm` option. Is there any other matlab xml parser that can work with `-nojvm`?

Thanks, 
- U

Comment: I didn't know the built in xml reader used JVM, but there are alternatives on the MATLAB Central File Exchange, such as [this one](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4278-xml-toolbox).  Why are you using `-nojvm` out of curiosity?

Comment: Do you have to run it with the `-nojvm` option? How about `matlab -nodisplay -nosplash -nodesktop`? Many XML parsers are written in Java, including the SAX parser that `parseXML`/`xmlread` uses. This one appears to be written in Matlab and c mex: [XMLTree](http://www.artefact.tk/software/matlab/xml/). Good parsers are not easy to write however, so be wary.

Comment: @horchler and @chappjc, thanks for your suggestions, `nojvm` was a part of legacy code! I removed that and added `-nodisplay -nosplash -nodesktop` and xml parsing works :)!